# API error: bad value for restricted picklist field

Tags: rest-api, picklist

I'm working with the Salesforce REST API (version 41.0), and I have a MultiPicklist field in Salesforce on the Opportunity object. It has 5 possible values: Bierschbach, Black, Espeland, Hirsi, Meador.

The field does indicate that it should "Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set", but it does not have a default value.

I have been posting values to this field via the API like this: `Bierschbach;Black;Hirsi` as the API seems to want.

The API consistently returns this error:

> URL: https://myinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Opportunity
>
> Message: bad value for restricted picklist field: Bierschbach
>
> Code: 400

I've been trying to use [this help link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000250168&language=en_US&type=1) to determine why I can send one or more of the values that are defined as accepted values but have them rejected. The Opportunity object does not require anything with this field automatically, as far as I can tell.

I've noticed this issue in Python and PHP, in case that is relevant:

- Python code: `list_values = ";".join(form.getlist('list_field'))`
- PHP code: `$list_values = implode( ';', $object['list_field'] );`

What else can I be looking for? It seems like the issue must be in our Salesforce configuration, but perhaps there's something I am neglecting to send with the values?

Update: here's a more full example of what I'm sending to Salesforce:

- API path: sobjects/Opportunity
- Method: POST
- params:

  Array(
      [Name] => test opportunity
      [Opportunity_Subtype__c] => Donation: Individual
      [Member_benefit_special_thank_you_list__c] => Bierschbach;Black;Espeland
      [CloseDate] => 2017-12-22
      [StageName] => Closed Won
      [Type] => Donation
      [Datetime__c] => 2017-12-31T05:00:00+00:00
      [RecordTypeId] => 012F00000013GkqIAE
  )

I don't seem able to get that array to format nicely with indenting, but these are all the values that are being sent to the API.

As you can see there is a RecordTypeId, which specifies which kind of opportunity the record is, but it does not have any default values for the list I'm trying to send.

Comment: Can we see a little more of the payload you're sending?

Comment: @SebastianKessel Sure, I updated the post with what I'm sending in the request.

Comment: Check if the Bierschbach picklist value in Salesforce has a leading or trailing space.

Comment: Are the picklist values also limited by recordtype? If so maybe the one that is giving you an issue is not available for that recordtype

Comment: @DavidCheng it does not have a leading or trailing space.

Comment: @Eric can you say more about limiting picklist values by record type? How would that be done if it were happening? There's nothing obvious on the field settings about that, but maybe I would need to look somewhere else.

Comment: @Eric I think you were right here. I had to go to Customize -> Opportunities -> Record Types -> Default (and the other types) -> the picklist -> Edit, and move Available Values over to Selected values. Happy to accept an answer to this effect from you, or I can post one. Whatever works.

Comment: I’ll put it as an answer later today. Glad it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the picklist values are limited by recordtype? If so maybe the one that is giving you an issue is not available for that recordtype

go to Customize -> Opportunities -> Record Types -> Default (and the other types) -> the picklist -> Edit, and move Available Values over to Selected values